# How can I include every person ID only once when using panel survey data?

Tags: r, dataframe, panel-data

I have a data set of survey data over 30 years. Each participant in the data frame is given a personal ID. I have two questions regarding this data set.

Firstly, how can I print the number of different personal IDs, i.e., how many different persons are observed?

Secondly, how can I make sure I include every person only once, when making a regression analysis over all observations?

Until now, I just went with only including one survey year, yet, this severely limits my sample sice. Thus, I wanted to include obsevrations from a time frame of 5 years.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Without some example data and seeing what you've tried it hard to answer.  As a start point, if you have a dataframe `df` including a column `pID` for personal IDs then `unique(df$pID)` would list the unique ID's and `length(unique(df$pID))` would count them for you.

Comment: Tidyerse logic `group_by` pipe `nrow`. The group by is powerful for paneldata. You can filter `row_number` 1 for each group. But you should better use within variation. Why have a panel and not use it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is basic information and a minimal example when working with panel data in R.

**Question 1: Number of different personal IDs (units, people, firms, countries)**

```
 # Packages 
library(plm)
library(tidyverse)

# Data
data("Produc", package = "plm")

## (1) Tidyverse logic 
Produc %>% 
  group_by(state) %>% 
  nrow

[1] 816

## (2) panelr package 
library(panelr)

Produc <- panel_data(Produc, id = state, wave = year)
Produc

# Panel data:    816 × 11
# entities:      state [48]
# wave variable: year [1970, 1971, 1972, ... (17 waves)]
   state    year region   pcap   hwy water  util     pc   gsp   emp unemp
   <fct>   <int> <fct>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 ALABAMA  1970 6      15033. 7326. 1656. 6051. 35794. 28418 1010.   4.7
 2 ALABAMA  1971 6      15502. 7526. 1721. 6255. 37300. 29375 1022.   5.2
 3 ALABAMA  1972 6      15972. 7765. 1765. 6442. 38670. 31303 1072.   4.7
 4 ALABAMA  1973 6      16406. 7908. 1742. 6756. 40084. 33430 1136.   3.9
 5 ALABAMA  1974 6      16763. 8026. 1735. 7002. 42057. 33749 1170.   5.5
 6 ALABAMA  1975 6      17316. 8158. 1752. 7406. 43972. 33604 1155.   7.7
 7 ALABAMA  1976 6      17733. 8228. 1800. 7705. 50222. 35764 1207    6.8
 8 ALABAMA  1977 6      18112. 8366. 1845. 7901. 51085. 37463 1269.   7.4
 9 ALABAMA  1978 6      18480. 8511. 1961. 8009. 52604. 39964 1336.   6.3
10 ALABAMA  1979 6      18881. 8641. 2082. 8159. 54526. 40979 1362    7.1
# … with 806 more rows
```

**Question 2: How can I make sure I include every person only once, when making a regression analysis over all observations?**

Either you include ALL, then you have a pooled model, or you do a cross-section, subsetting/filtering for a particular time.

```
# pooling means all observations, all units in all time points
model_pooling <- plm(pcap ~ unemp + water + util + pc + gsp, 
                     data=Produc, 
                     effect = "individual", model = "pooling", 
                     index=c("state", "year"))

# cross-section
model_1970 <- plm(pcap ~ unemp + water + util + pc + gsp, 
                     data=Produc %>% filter(year == 1970), 
                     effect = "individual", model = "pooling", 
                     index=c("state", "year"))
  
library(stargazer)

stargazer(model_pooling, model_1970, type="text",
          column.labels = c("All", "Sample 1970"), model.numbers = FALSE)

==================================================================
                              Dependent variable:                 
             -----------------------------------------------------
                                     pcap                         
                         All                    Sample 1970       
------------------------------------------------------------------
unemp                  26.116                    -223.077         
                      (35.381)                   (177.538)        
                                                                  
water                 1.421***                   1.880***         
                       (0.085)                    (0.198)         
                                                                  
util                  1.118***                   1.045***         
                       (0.019)                    (0.068)         
                                                                  
pc                    0.030***                    0.026*          
                       (0.005)                    (0.015)         
                                                                  
gsp                   0.056***                   0.073***         
                       (0.008)                    (0.024)         
                                                                  
Constant            2,057.508***               2,569.209***       
                      (240.335)                  (882.888)        
                                                                  
------------------------------------------------------------------
Observations             816                        48            
R2                      0.994                      0.998          
Adjusted R2             0.994                      0.997          
F Statistic  27,696.970*** (df = 5; 810) 3,696.803*** (df = 5; 42)
==================================================================
Note:                                  *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

When you have a panel, we strongly recommend to use the additional variation that it provides. Please specify your regression model, if I got you wrong. Alternatively, you can filter for the first observation per person (unit) ignoring the time.